# Angular 5 - How to dynamically add event on a DOM element?

Tags: angular, typeahead.js

I'm try to implement a search input as the one on "Medium" website by adding a new suggestion (based on the input context for full text search) at the top of the list of the current suggestions. I'm on an angular 5 project and I use typeahead  for research module.

So this is how I add new suggestion on top off typeahead list:

```js
var nba = [{
  "team": "Boston Celtics"
}, {
  "team": "Dallas Mavericks"
}, {
  "team": "Brooklyn Nets"
}, {
  "team": "Houston Rockets"
}, {
  "team": "New York Knicks"
}, {
  "team": "Memphis Grizzlies"
}, {
  "team": "Philadelphia 76ers"
}, {
  "team": "New Orleans Hornets"
}, {
  "team": "Toronto Raptors"
}, {
  "team": "San Antonio Spurs"
}];
var teams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: nba
});
var search = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: [{
    'team': 'xxxxx'
  }]
});

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    hint: false,
    minlenght: 2
  },

  {
    name: 'search-in-team',
    display: 'team',
    source: teams,
    templates: {
      header: '<div class="group">Teams</div>'
    }
  });

$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:render', (event, suggestions, async, dataset) => {
  $('.tt-dataset').prepend('<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable added" > <span class="strong"> Search for "' + $('.typeahead').val() + '"</span></div>');
});

$('.typeahead').bind('typeahead:select', (ev, suggestion) => {
  alert(suggestion.team)
});
```

```css
.group {
  padding: .5rem .5rem 0rem .5rem;
  font-family: $avenir_next;
  color: $color-47;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<div id='multiple-datasets'>
  <input type="text" id="sskSearch" class="typeahead" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

I have an alert when I click on the suggestion under "Teams", But nothing happen when click on the new first element I manually added ("Search for 'xxxx').
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWMRq.png)

Any help Please!!!

Comment: bro - your code not looks good - read some tutorials about angular first (and make examples) - this is honest and good advice

Comment: If you found the Angular search suggestion on Medium then why are you using typeheadjs?

Comment: Hi @Tatali and welcome in stackoverflow, you should provide us minimal sample of your code who can reproduce the bug.

Comment: @Sanjeetkumar, I'm tyring to use angular wtih typeahead   to reproduce "Medium search tab" in my own application.

Comment: @Yanis-git , I try to provide more codes and some explanations of my issues